# assigning kth elemnt of a list to 'obj_k'

Tags: python-2.7, variable-assignment

I am working with Python 2.7. Given a list of n objects i want to assign the variable 'obj_k' to the kth element of the list.

For example given the list

```
mylist = [1,'car', 10]
```

i am looking for a way to do the following for me

```
obj_0 = 1
obj_1 = 'car'
obj_2 = 10
```

This seems pretty basic, but i don't see how to do it. Morally i am thinking about something along the lines of

```
for i in range(len(mylist)): obj_i = mylist[i]
```

which is obviously syntactically invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if dynamically creating variable is a good idea but here is what you want. If I were you, I probably use a dictionary to store the variables to just avoid polluting the namespace.

```
In [1]: mylist = [1,'car', 10]

In [2]: print obj_1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2f857dd36a40> in <module>()
----> 1 print obj_1

NameError: name 'obj_1' is not defined

In [3]: for i,c in enumerate(mylist):
   ...:     globals()['obj_'+str(i)] = c
   ...:     

In [4]: obj_1
Out[4]: 'car'
```

Comment: Thank you. I also i think it is not generally a good idea, but i was still wandering how it would work.